# Move file to folder in dropbox

Tags: ios, ipad

How do I move a file from one folder to a different folder in Dropbox? I cannot find any links or tabs to do this from the iOS / iPad app.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working from the iPhone app so it may be different on the iPad, but try this.

1. Browse to the file you want to move.
2. Tap the ellipsis ( ... ) at the top of the screen next to the folder name, and choose 'Edit'.
3. Tap the checkbox next to the file you want to move.
4. Tap 'Move' at the bottom of the screen.
5. Navigate to the folder you want to move the file to.  You can use the arrow at the top left to go to the parent folder.
6. When you are in the desired destination folder, tap 'Choose' at the bottom right corner of the screen.

Comment: In the version on the iPad that I am using, it is not called *Edit* but *Select*, otherwise it is the same.

Answer (score -1):

*I misread the OP but I'll leave it here just incase:*

You can drag and drop files from one folder to another on the Website or you can rightclick the file and click "Move". You can also use the Dropbox folder on your Mac (If you've got the client installed) like a normal finder folder.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are trying to do this on an iPad? If so, I recommend looking into [AirFile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airfile/id560145740?mt=8). Not only can you move files around, you can move/copy them between different cloud services.